# how to call SetExtendedUI on CMFCToolBarFontComboBox

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am creating a MFC application based on example: https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples/tree/master/VC2010Samples/MFC/Visual%20C%2B%2B%202008%20Feature%20Pack/WordPad
now i want to change the way to expand font name drop list in toolbar from DOWN key to F4. It seems i need to get the combobox and call `SetExtenedUI(FALSE)` on it, but i dont know where to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i switched to CComboBoxEx which works fine

Answer (score 0):

To change the extended UI flag on a `CComboBox`, you call its [`CComboBox::SetExtendedUI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class#setextendedui) member. When you have a [`CMFCToolBarFontComboBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfctoolbarfontcombobox-class) you need to get to its combo box first. Since it inherits from [`CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfctoolbarcomboboxbutton-class) you can use its [`CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton::GetComboBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfctoolbarcomboboxbutton-class#getcombobox) member to get a `CComboBox*`.

```cpp
CMFCToolBarFontComboBox* pFontButton = ...;
CComboBox* pComboBox = pFontButton->GetComboBox();
pComboBox->SetExtendedUI(FALSE);
```

Comment: yes i know these, my question is where should i put these codes, i tried to put them to void CWordPadView::OnFontname(), but it does not work, SetExtendedUI(FALSE) returns CB_OKAY but F4 still doesn't work.

Comment: Show a [mcve] then.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples/tree/master/VC2010Samples/MFC/Visual%20C%2B%2B%202008%20Feature%20Pack/WordPad, all i need is to make F4 work on font name combobox

Comment: i wrote an app to call SendMessage(m_hWnd, CB_SETEXTENDEDUI, bExtended, 0L) on target combobox, if target is standard CComboBox, it works. but CMFCToolBarFontComboBox does not work, it seems like CMFCToolBarFontComboBox  does not accpet this flag.

Comment: A [mcve] needs to be minimal, and be part of the question.